# Trigonometry find area of triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Triangle ABC is right angeled with right angle at corner C and angle a at corner A. Calculate triangle area if we know that c=|AB|=10 and tan a = 3/2

I get side |AC| = 2
side |CB| = 3
and side |AB| = 10 but this can not be case because it's not pythagoras definition then

Greetings from RUssia
Vladimir Vlostok

Comment: You are correct, if $\tan A=3/2$ then the length os the hypotenuse id $\sqrt{13}$. However, if the hypotenuse $c=10$ then the other two sides are of length $8$ and $6$.

Comment: Taking lengths as such $ \tan ⁡A=3/2$  then the length of the hypotenuse is$\sqrt{13} $ which is scaled up as $10$ Find magiification factor from $AB$ and apply it to $CB,CA$

Answer (score 1):

$A = 0.5 \cdot |AB||AC| \sin(a)$

$\tan(a)=\frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)}=\frac{\sin(a)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(a)}}$. Solve this equaiton for $\sin(a)$:

$\sin(a)=\frac{\tan(a)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(a)}}=\frac{3/2}{\sqrt{1+9/4}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$
 and plug it into the previous equation. Note, that the previous statements are only true for $0\leq a \leq \pi/2$, which is fulfilled.

Comment: so how big is triangle area then?

Comment: @Vladimir so the area = 300/13

Comment: @MrYouMath Check your formula for area.It is missing a factor $|AC|$

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot that :D.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Triang_tana]
$$b^{\,2} \left( {1 + \tan ^{\,2} \alpha } \right) = c^{\,2}  = 100$$
$$b^2=400/13$$
$$Area=ab/2=1/2\;b^2\;tan\alpha=1/2\; 400/13\; 3/2=300/13$$

Answer (score 0):

From the tangent of $a$, you know that $\frac{BC}{AC} = \frac{3}{2}$.

So let $BC = 3x$ and $AC = 2x$

By Pythagoras, $AC^2 + BC^2 = AB^2 \implies 13x^2 = 100 \implies x^2 = \frac{100}{13}$

Area of triangle = $\frac{1}{2} AC \cdot BC = 3x^2 = \frac{300}{13}$